# Filter out different fields for each line with AWK

Tags: sql, bash, hadoop, awk, impala

I have these commands to show me the number of files in partition.

```
echo '' > ~/partitions_mkt_296 ; impala-shell -i czmorehr -q "use cz_prd_mkt_op; show tables;" -B | while read a; do impala-shell -q "show partitions cz_prd_mkt_op.${a};" -B -i czmorehr >> ~/partitions_mkt_296.txt; done
```

The problem is that in the resulting file - the number Im looking for is sometimes in the 3rd, 4th  or 7th field (depending on the number of partitions the table has.
I would like to use awk to extract all possible columns and then filter out those I dont want to on the premise they contain either "=", "." or "-". - and display only the fields not containing these.
Is this possible to achieve?

The sample input is:

```
2017052118  -1  7   197.70MB    NOT CACHED  NOT CACHED  PARQUET false   hdfs://MORPHEUS/user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_mkt_op.db/edw_customers/pr_load_time=2017052118
2017052209  -1  8   198.31MB    NOT CACHED  NOT CACHED  PARQUET false   hdfs://MORPHEUS/user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_mkt_op.db/edw_customers/pr_load_time=2017052209
0   2017062006  -1  4   232.42MB    NOT CACHED  NOT CACHED  PARQUET false   hdfs://MORPHEUS/user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/gngi__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/pr_start_time=2017062006
0   2017062007  -1  5   347.36MB    NOT CACHED  NOT CACHED  PARQUET false   hdfs://MORPHEUS/user/hive/warehouse/cz_prd_ntw_op.db/gngi__24_/pr_comp_ver=0/
```

In the first two lines, I want to extract the numbers 7,8 as well as table name -edw_customers. In the last two lines, I need to extract numbers 4,5 and the table name- gngi__24_

Comment: post the sample input

Comment: why `2017052118` should be ignored?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It should not - from this line, I want to extract the "7" in 3rd field and then the "edw_customers" . The problem is the third and fourth line has the number Im interested in different field (4th)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '$11~/^hdfs/{ match($11,/_op\.db\/([^\/]+)/,a); num=$3; tn=a[1] }
     $12~/^hdfs/{ match($12,/_op\.db\/([^\/]+)/,a); num=$4; tn=a[1] }{ print num,tn }' file
```

The output:

```
7 edw_customers
8 edw_customers
4 gngi__24_
5 gngi__24_
```

Answer (score 0):

With any awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/.*_op\.db\/|\/.*/,"",$NF); print $(NF-8), $NF}' file
7 edw_customers
8 edw_customers
4 gngi__24_
5 gngi__24_
```